# Sencha Touch Load Mask

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have list and pull down to refresh plugin in it. When the refresh function fires i would like to show the load mask. But its not showing there. when i commented  `store.removeAll();` line i can see the loadmask working. I dont konw whats the problem with store.removeAll(). Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

```
                {
                    xclass: 'Ext.ux.PullRefreshFn',
                    pullRefreshText: 'Pull down for refresh Contacts!',
                    refreshFn: function() {
                        console.log('pull refresh working');
                        Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
                            xtype: 'loadmask',
                            message: 'Please Wait...'
                        });
                        var store = Ext.getStore('Contactsstore');
                        store.removeAll();

                        var url = apiurl+'Contact.ashx?switch=GetContactList&api_id=4&getDataAgain=true';
                        store.getProxy().setUrl(url);
                        store.loadPage(1,{
                            callback: function (records, operation, success, response) {
                                if (success==1) {

                                    Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);

                                } else {
                                    Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);


                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Ext.getCmp('searchcontact').reset();
                    }
                }
```

Here is my Store configuration

```
Ext.define('WinReo.store.Contactsstore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires: [
        'WinReo.model.Contactsmodel'
    ],

    config: {
        storeId: 'Contactsstore',
        defaultRootProperty: 'items',
        model: 'WinReo.model.Contactsmodel',
        autoLoad: false,
        pageSize: 20,
        proxy: {

            type: 'ajax',
            method:'post',
            id: 'Contactsstoreproxy',
            url:apiurl+'Contact.ashx?switch=GetContactList&api_id=4&getDataAgain=false',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
                callback:{
                    succes:
                        if(store.getCount()!=0){
                            var RecordCount=store.getAt(0).get('RecordCount');
                            //console.log('RecordCount',RecordCount);
                            store.setTotalCount(RecordCount);
                            var storectscount = store.getTotalCount();
                            //Ext.Msg.alert('Store Total count',storectscount, Ext.emptyFn);
                        }

                }


            }

        }
    } 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading masks won't get rendered until the browser has a chance to render them, and that won't happen until your Javascript code completes. I suspect that for some reason, the `removeAll` call isn't completing quickly (or at all), or an event listener on `clear` isn't completing like it needs to. Check your store's configuration for `syncRemovedRecords: true` and `autoSync: true`. You can also try `removeAll(true)` to keep the `clear` event from firing.

**Update**

Looking at your store definition, I can see at least one problem: Your `load` listener doesn't look like it's defined properly. You're defining a `callback` field inside of a function (which isn't going to compile), and 'succes' is misspelled. Is this what you had in mind?

```
       load: function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
            if(successful === true && store.getCount()!=0){
                    var RecordCount=store.getAt(0).get('RecordCount');
                    store.setTotalCount(RecordCount);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That may be the reason i have a large tree store, so when i user removeAll() its taking too much time to remove records. Tried remoeAll(true) and also checked my store configuration. But no success. I have edited my question and attached my store code. Can u plz check it..Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, changed my store call back function, but the load mask issue still persist.

Comment: Am using this plugin http://docs.kawanoshinobu.com/touch/#!/api/Ext.ux.AccordionList to build an accordion list. So am loading a treestore. I dont know is that the reason its very slow. Did u get find any solution, please let me know

Comment: Dibish... You could try out the store with a very small test dataset and see if that helps.

Comment: Now its working, as you said my store is taking too much time to clear data. Now am using   storectn.data.clear(); to clear store quickly instead of store.removeAll(). Am marking your answer as correct it gave me a valuable suggestion to solve my issue